# Windows clipboard CRLF/LF passing wrong for one user

Tags: c#, clipboard, citrix, batch-file

We have a pair of applications.  One is written in C# and uses something like:

```
 string s = "alpha\r\nbeta\r\ngamma\r\ndelta";
 // Actually there's wrapper code here to make sure this works.
 System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(s, true);
```

To put a list of items onto the clipboard.  Another application (in WinBatch) then picks up the list using a ClipGet() function.  (We use the clipboard functions to give people the option of editing the list in notepad or something, without having to actually cut-and-paste every time.)

In this particular environment, we have many users on one system via Citrix.  Many using these pairs of programs.

Just *one* user is having the problem where the line delimiters in the text are getting switched from CRLF to LF somewhere between the SetDataObject() and the CLipGet().  I could explain this in a mixed Unix/Windows environment, but there is no Unix here.  No unix-y utilities anywhere near this system either.  Other users on the same server, no problems at all.  It's like something in Windows/Citrix is being "helpful" when we really don't want it, but just for this one guy.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing their profile on Citrix?  That seems to be the solution to many many user specific Citrix problems.

Answer (score 1):

Does Environment.NewLine behave differently on Citrix environments?  If so, it may give you a good option that works for all users instead of \r\n.